# Does $\int_{t=0}^{\tau}F(r)\cos(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t=0$ even with a factor of the integrand independent of the integration variable?

Tags: calculus, integration, intuition, trigonometric-integrals

Can we guarantee that $$\int_{t=0}^{\tau}F(r)\cos(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t=0$$ where $\tau$ is the period of the cosine function with angular frequency defined as $$\omega=\frac{2\pi}{\tau}$$ and $F(r)$ is some unknown function of *position* $r$ **only**?

In other words, $r$ does not depend on time $t$.

I know that in *general* $$\fbox{$\color{red}{\int_{t=0}^{\tau}F(r)\,\mathrm{d}t\ne 0}$}\tag{$\color{red}{1}$}$$
since we will get a function of $\tau$; and $$\int_{t=0}^{\tau}\cos(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t= 0$$
since we have integrated over 1 full period.

But I'm not sure about whether $$\int_{t=0}^{\tau}F(r)\cos(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t$$ 
is zero or not.

It was my understanding that I may take out factors of the integrand independent of the integration variable $t$:
$$\int_{t=0}^{\tau}F(r)\cos(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t=F(r)\int_{t=0}^{\tau}\cos(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t=0$$
as $F(r)$ is being treated as a constant.

$\fbox{$\color{red}{\text{But it is equation (1) that is confusing me here}}$}$.

So can I conclude that since $r$ is not a function of $t$  $$\int_{t=0}^{\tau}F(r)\cos(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t=0?$$

---

### EDIT:

One user has agreed that I may pull the factor $F(r)$ out as a constant since it does not depend on $t$.

Now, I just need confirmation:

Does $$\int_{t=0}^{\tau}F(r)\cos(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t=0$$ or not?

A simple yes or no answer/comment will suffice; thanks very much.

Comment: Is $r$ taken to be a function of $t$, or not? If it isn't, then it's just a constant and can be pulled out of the integral. If it is, then your integrand is really $F(r(t))\cos(\omega t)$ and you certainly can't pull $F(r(t))$ out.

Comment: @Semi Thanks for your reply, $r$ is not a function of $t$ as I mentioned in my question; but I'll make that part more clear if it's not so.

Comment: @Semiclassical I have edited the question to be more clear; I just need confirmation. If $r$ is not a function of $t$ can I conclude that $\int_{t=0}^{\tau}F(r)\cos(\omega t)\mathrm{d}t=0$ or not? I know it seems trivial to you, but it's not so obvious to me. Many thanks, please consider making answer so I can bring the question to a closure?

Comment: You're reasoning is correct. $r$ is not a function of $t$, so you can pull $F(r)$ out of the integral (which is $0$).